# Linq to list, select only four columns from DB?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, anonymous-types

My table has over 15 columns and I only want to retrieve `four` of those columns to store in memory. However trying the below method, gives the error `cannot explicitly convert List to IEnumerable`. Is this also the correct approach? Have a feeling I am missing a where clause or something? CompanyID is the index.

```
IEnumerable<Company> company = _db.Company.Select(a => new
{
    CompanyId = Convert.ToString(a.CompanyId),
    CompanyType = a.CompanyType,
    CompanyName = a.CompanyName,
    Email = a.Email
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create an [Anonymous Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with your `Select` statement and you can not convert `List<definedAnonymousType>` to `IEnumerable<Company>`.

Use `var` instead of `IEnumerable<Company>`.

```
var company = _db.Company.Select(a => new
{
    CompanyId = Convert.ToString(a.CompanyId),
    CompanyType = a.CompanyType,
    CompanyName = a.CompanyName,
    Email = a.Email
}).ToList();
```

then your `company` type will be `List<definedAnonymousType>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can create CompanyLite dto with the exact properties you want and convert data to that

```
var companyLite = _db.Company.Select(a => new CompanyLite 
{
   CompanyId = Convert.ToString(a.CompanyId),
   CompanyType = a.CompanyType,
   CompanyName = a.CompanyName,
   Email = a.Email
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I would assume the downvote is due to this being unnecessary - the framework will create a class at runtime when you use an anonymous type, as shown in @dotctor's answer. So, your answer is not wrong per se, it just isn't as helpful as the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tieson T. i really appreciate that. i thought there is wrong in my answer. but anyway this is like different way of approaching the same. ex if he needs some concrete class implementation on this time rather converting it again he can use directly this.